# Add existing API to Azure API Management Service using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I need to add existing (deployed) API APP to API management service through **Powershell** command.
When I am trying it using 'New-AzureRmApiManagementApi' command it will create new API but it did not import the operations.
There are many ways to import API from file or URL but I need to add existing API
I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/apimanagement.servicemanagement/v1.1.4/new-azurermapimanagementapi link
Is there any way to add existing API App to API management service?

The request is -

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ApiManag
ement/service/xxxxxxxxxx/apis/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?api-version=2016-10-10

Headers:

Body:
{
  "name": "test",
  "serviceUrl": "https://test.azure-api.net/",
  "path": "test",
  "protocols": [
    "Http",
    "Https"
  ],
  "type": "Http"
}
```

I am looking for command which takes API URL suffix,API APP,Name as parameters

Comment: well, this is definitely possible using powershell, can you post the http request that the powershell is performing? you can get it using your powershell command with a `-debug` switch (it will be somewhere in the middle of all the output)

Comment: @4c74356b41 mentioned in question

Comment: well, unless there is some other powershell command you are out of luck, you can use rest to do that, if you cant figure this, I can create an answer in an hour (gotta rush somewhere now, sorry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can do that with a REST call described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apis#Apis_CreateOrUpdate).

To get the bearer token use the following powershell code:

```
$body = @{
    client_id= '{Azure AD Application GUID}'
    client_secret = '{Azure AD Application secret}'
    grant_Type = 'clientcredentials'
    resource = 'https://graph.windows.net/'
}
$result = iwr https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Azure_AD_Tenant_GUID}/oauth2/token -Method Post -Body $body
$BearerToken = ($result.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).access_token
```

Azure AD Application Service Principal should have the rights to API Management
And issue the following REST call:

```
$url = 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/xxxxxxxxxx/apis/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?api-version=2016-10-10&import=true&path=xxx'
$headers = @{'Content-Type' = 'application/vnd.swagger.link+json'; 'Authorization' = $BearerToken}
$body = {
  "name": "test",
##### serviceUrl needs a link to SWAGGER.JSON, not to the root of the api #####
  "serviceUrl": "https://test.azure-api.net/swagger.json", 
  "path": "test",
  "protocols": [
    "Http",
    "Https"
  ],
  "type": "Http"
}
```

The `path` query parameter in the URL is the name of the API Management backend service associated with this API.

If you want to add API schema in the request you can do that but substituting the body of the request with your swagger schema and substituting 'Content-Type' header with `vnd.swagger.doc+json`

ps. maybe for the `Authorization` header you need this: `"Bearer " + $BearerToken`

Comment: what if I don't have swagger.json file?

Comment: well, your api should be described somehow? if not, how do you expect API Management to import it?

Comment: I don't have swagger.json exist physically rather I got in location - http://xxx.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/v1. When I put this path It throws Bad Request.

Comment: well, this page probably returns not just a json file, right? you need to get the json file

Comment: does it use swagger.json or reflector to parse assemblies in the case of adding of existing Azure Api App?

Comment: @Rohi_Dev_1.0, do you have Swashbuckle configured correctly? If so it show return swagger json for above path.

Comment: @KonstantinSalavatov I have the correct swagger file. I found simple workarround is to download the swagger file before importing any API. It's working. :)